# Text not wrapping around image (CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I would like the Images on the right hand side width 500px. However the only way I have managed that is to set the article's width at 65% and the image's at 35% which I understand can interfere with responsive design.

I have tried using Float:left (and right as appropriate) and Margin:10px and Display:inline on the image and article. I have also tried moving the image into the article element (with the CSS changed to reflect it's new position) but the image stays below the text.

```css
.middle{
    display:inline-block;
}

article{
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

article h2{
  font-family:'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:#1C5C35;
}

article ul {
    list-style-image:url(images/bullet\ point\ dark\ green\ small.jpg);
    margin-left:20px;
}

aside div.stone_pic img{
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:500px;
```

```html
<section class='middle'> 

<article>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>PLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in r</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br>
<br>
The full treatment comes with an 18-month guarantee .
</p>

</article>

<aside>
    <div class="stone_pic">
    <img src="images/aside resized.jpg" alt="side image- stones before and after pressure washing">
    </div>
</aside>

</section>
```

Can someone with more experience suggest why the text isn't wrapping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `float` determines how content coming _after_ the element you apply it to in the DOM, floats around this element. You have your article containing all the text first here, and only then comes your aside element containing the image - it would need to be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

a) apply `float: right;` to the `aside` element instead of the image, otherwise aside will automatically have 100% width and be a block element

b)  move the `aside` element to the position where you want the image to start (in my adaption of your code below I moved it to before the article)

```css
.middle{
    display:inline-block;
}

article{
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

article h2{
  font-family:'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color:#1C5C35;
}

article ul {
    list-style-image:url(images/bullet\ point\ dark\ green\ small.jpg);
    margin-left:20px;
}

aside {
    float: right;
}
aside div.stone_pic img{
    margin-left:10px;
    width:500px;
```

```html
<section class='middle'> 
<aside>
    <div class="stone_pic">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="side image- stones before and after pressure washing">
    </div>
</aside>
<article>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>PLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in r</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur<br>
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <br>
<br>
The full treatment comes with an 18-month guarantee .
</p>

</article>



</section>
```